# How can I compare two directories to update a log file in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I am attempting to compare two directories and then update the log file after determining what files are different between the two, but I keep getting error messages saying that it expects an integer result in the line [ if $userinput -eq $userinput.log ]. Is there a way to compare these two that I am missing? Here is the script I have written.

```
userinput=$1
if [ ! -d "$userinput" ];
then
        echo "Usage: dirlog.sh directory_name" 1>&2
        exit 0
else
        if [ ! -f "$userinput.log" ];
        then
                ls -l > $userinput.log
                echo ".logfile created for $userinput"
        elif [ -f "$userinput.log" ];
        then
                if [ $userinput -eq $userinput.log  ]; #if they are different
                then
                        differences=diff -rq $userinput $userinput.log
                        for file in $differences
                        do
                                echo "$file missing from directory $userinput"
                        done
                else
                        echo "no files missing from directory $userinput"
                fi
                #Update this no matter what
                ls -l > $userinput.log
                echo "logfile updated for directory $userinput"
        fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two directories with the `diff -r` command. This will show you all files that differ, which files are missing from one directory to another. The `--brief` option or `--summary` option will simply list the differences and not the content of the files.

Now, about your `if [ $userinput -eq $userinput.log  ];`...

In shell, a variable could hold numeric or could hold alphanumeric data. Let's take something like this:

```
foo="0456"
bar="456"
```

In the above, `$foo` and `$bar` could be strings or numbers. If I think of them as numbers, they're equal. However, if they are strings, they're not equal.

Here's another example:

```
foo="123"
bar="45"
```

Which is greater? Again, it depends whether `$foo` and `$bar` are being treated as strings or numbers. If I treat them numerically `$foo` is greater. However, if I treat them as text strings, `$bar` is greater because the first character of `$bar` which is `4` comes after the first character of `$foo`, `1`.

So, how does bash know whether I want numeric or string comparison? Simple, Bash provides me with two different sets of comparison operators. One is for strings and one is for text:

```
                    String   Numeric
                    ------   -------
Equals                =       -eq
Greater Than          >       -gt
Less Than             <       -lt
Not equals           !=       -ne
Greater Than/Equals  >=       -ge
Less Than/Equals     <=       -le
```

In your case, you want to compare two strings and you're using `-eq`. This is why you're getting the error that the `-eq` operator expects numeric results. By the way, if you're using Bash or Kornshell, you should go ahead and use the doubled square brackets `[[ ... ]]`. These are less error prone and have a few more nice features such as pattern matching:

```
if [[ $userinput == "$userinput.log" ]]
```

However, I really recommend you to use he `diff -r --brief` command for comparing two directories.